# How can I see who and where is currently mounting at on my PC via nfs?

Tags: mount, nfs, command

I thought the UNIX command `showmount -a` shows the current info of nfs: who is mounting on, and what directory of my computer it is attached at. But, when I use this command, it replies nothing like:

`All mount points on MY-COMPUTER:`

I even tried this command while some other host was coping a huge file from my PC via nfs. But, it said nothing though the file coping process was done successfully

What am I missing here? What is a correct command to see the current nfs detailed information?

Comment: Maybe answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34919597/how-to-get-the-list-of-clients-connected-to-an-nfs-server-within-a-local-network helps

Comment: What's your PC running?

Comment: @Marvin I checked it and I understood :)

Comment: @roaima Linux Mint 19.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you are missing anything.  Depending on your distro, showmount -a can at times be a bit buggy.  I have observed this same issue on CentOS/RHEL 5 and 6.  No worries try this `netstat` command to grep out for NFS and NFSD.  I have a dev box at home, NFS service running, but no remote mounts yet.  In this example I will check for RPC, a service that usually runs in conjunction with NFS, less some later versions of NFS.

```
   watch -n 1 "netstat -antup| grep -i rpc"     

   Every 1.0s: netstat -antup| grep -i rpc                                                      
   Sun Mar 31 20:39:20 2019
   udp9/rpc.st0td             0.0.0.0:*                           26489/rpc.statd
   udp0.0.0.0:09365           0.0.0.0:*                           26499/rpc.mountd
   udp0.0.0.0:00048           0.0.0.0:*                           2692/rpcbind
   udp0.0.0.0:011             0.0.0.0:*                           2692/rpcbind
   udp0.0.0.0:040             0.0.0.0:*                           26489/rpc.statd
   udp627.0.0.1:802           :::*                                26499/rpc.mountd
   udp6                       :::*                                2692/rpcbind
   udp6::20048                :::*                                2692/rpcbind
   #### OUTPUT TRUNCATED ####
```

In your case, substitute NFS and/or NFSD for RPC in my example.  You will see all the NFSD threads which are by default 8 threads.  Yous should see the local port and the remote port on remote hosts who have mounted NFS. I use `watch` to well, watch it.  Something else to try: on occasion I have "fixed" the `showmount -a` by restarting the NFS service.  Here's the command which can vary based on distro:

CentOS 5:  `service nfsd restart`

CentOS 7:  `systemctl restart nfs-config.service`
 and then  `systemctl restart nfs-server.service`

One more thing:  the `/proc/fs/nfsd` DIR (distro dependent) has a lot of great stats to monitor NFS performance.  For CentOS/RHEL 6/7 the `pool_threads` shows the MAX number of NFS requests that can be handled simultaneously.  `pool_stats` is where the good stuff is.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. It solved my question :)
I put your command line into a shell script.
Nice idea to monitor my network!